# How to pass an (a,b) function to a method and use it?

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming

I have two methods that look very much the same:

```
public Book minus(BigDecimal parameterA, BigDecimal parameterB, BigDecimal parameterC) {
    return new Book(
        this.a.subtract(parameterA),
        this.b.subtract(parameterB),
        this.c.subtract(parameterC)
    );
}
```

and

```
public Book plus(BigDecimal parameterA, BigDecimal parameterB, BigDecimal parameterC) {
    return new Book(
        this.a.add(parameterA),
        this.b.add(parameterB),
        this.c.add(parameterC)
    );
}
```

I wish to group these into one single helper method that takes a function as argument:

```
private Book apply(Function function, BigDecimal parameterA, BigDecimal parameterB, BigDecimal parameterC);
```

a, b & c are BigDecimal class fields;

Can you help me understand how I can pass such method?

I am running Java 8

Thank you

> SOLVED

```
public Book minus(BigDecimal parameterA, BigDecimal parameterB, BigDecimal parameterC) {
    return apply(BigDecimal::subtract, parameterA, parameterB, parameterC);
}

public Book minus(BigDecimal parameterA, BigDecimal parameterB, BigDecimal parameterC) {
    return apply(BigDecimal::add, parameterA, parameterB, parameterC);
}

private Book apply(BinaryOperator<BigDecimal> operator, BigDecimal parameterA, BigDecimal parameterB, BigDecimal parameterC) {
    return new Book(
        operator.apply(a, parameterA),
        operator.apply(b, parameterB),
        operator.apply(c, parameterC)
    );
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `this.a`? It isn't `BigDecimal` because it doesn't have a `minus` or `plus` methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a Function, or in this case a BiFunction as it takes two inputs or `BinaryOperator` as @HankD suggests.

```
private Book apply(BinaryOperator<BigDecimal> function, 
                   BigDecimal parameterA,
                   BigDecimal parameterB,
                   BigDecimal parameterC);
```

You can call it with

```
Book b1 = apply(BigDecimal::add, a, b, c);
Book b2 = apply(BigDecimal::subtract, a, b, c);
```

Comment: `BigDecimal.plus(BigDecimal)` doesn't exist.

Comment: did you mean `BigDecimal::add`?

Comment: Yes I meant BigDecimal::add, sorry tried to generify the question by removing extraneous code and made a copy & paste error.